# Form of the MTZ black hole hair from Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, klein-gordon-equation, no-hair-theorem

In the MTZ [paper "Exact black hole solution with a minimally coupled scalar field" by
Martinez, Troncoso, & Zanelli](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0406111), the scalar hair field is given by

$$\phi(r)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi G_N}}\textrm{arctanh}\left(\frac{G_N \mu}{r+G_N\mu}\right)  $$

This can be solved from the potential ansantz

$$V(\phi)=-\frac{3}{4\pi G\ell^2}\sinh^2\sqrt{\frac{4\pi G}{3}}\phi $$

coupled with the Klein-Gordon equation

$$g^{11} \phi''=f(r)\phi''=\frac{dV}{d\phi}$$

which, given their form of the metric, becomes

$$\frac{r(r+2G \mu)}{(r+G\mu)^2}\frac{1}{r^2/\ell^2-(1+\frac{G\mu}{r})^2}\phi''=-\frac{3}{4\pi G\ell^2}\sinh^2 \sqrt{\frac{4\pi G}{3}}$$

Unfortunately, when I solve this differential equation, I got a complicated expression which bares little resemblance to the value of $\phi(r)$ given above. When I plug in the original form of $\phi(r)$ into the above, the left-hand side becomes

$$\frac{3}{4\pi G\ell^2}\frac{2G\mu}{r(r+G\mu)(r+2G\mu)}  $$

Which has residual $r$ dependence not captured on the right-hand side. Is there something I'm missing in the derivation? Is it more complicated (or simple) then the above approach makes it seem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Klein-Gordon equation is not correct. It is not just $g^{11}\phi''$. It is much more complicated. You will need to calculate the Christoffel symbols first then the box operator will be $\Box \phi= \nabla^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}\phi$. Now, the second covariant derivative is of course a partial cause $\phi$ is a scalar, but now $\partial_{\mu}\phi$ is a covector. And this is how the Christoffels appear(the first covariant derivative acts now on a covector). Also, bare in mind that the MTZ black hole has two degrees of freedom for the metric. The differential equation will eventually be (checked with xAct):

$$\cfrac{1}{ra(r)^{2}}\Big[ra(r)b(r)\phi ''(r) + \phi ' (r)\big(rb(r)a'(r) + a(r)(2b(r) + rb'(r))\big)\Big] = \cfrac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi}$$

where i assume a metric ansatz of the form:

$$ ds^{2} = a(r)\big(-b(r)dt^{2} + \cfrac{1}{b(r)}dr^{2} + r^{2}(d\theta^2 + sinh^{2}\theta dφ^2) \big)$$

Also, $\phi(r)$ if i remember correctly is a part of $sinh^{2}$, not a multiplication factor.

Christoffels used for the box term:

$Γ^{r}_{tt} = \frac{b(r) \left(b(r) a'(r)+a(r) b'(r)\right)}{2 a(r)}$

$Γ^{r}_{rr} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{a'(r)}{a(r)}-\frac{b'(r)}{b(r)}\right)$

$Γ^{r}_{θθ} = -\frac{r b(r) \left(r a'(r)+2 a(r)\right)}{2 a(r)}$

$Γ^{r}_{φφ} = -\frac{r b(r) \sinh ^2(\theta ) \left(r a'(r)+2 a(r)\right)}{2 a(r)}$

$\Box \phi = g^{μν}\nabla_{μ}\nabla_{ν}\phi = g^{μν}\nabla_{μ}\partial_{ν}\phi = g^{μν}\Big(\partial_{μ}\partial_{ν}\phi - Γ^{α}_{μν}\partial_{α}\phi\Big) = g^{rr}\phi '' - g^{tt}Γ^{r}_{tt}\phi ' - g^{rr}Γ^{r}_{rr}\phi ' - g^{θθ}Γ^{r}_{θθ}\phi ' - g^{φφ}Γ^{r}_{φφ}\phi ' =...$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I'm a little confused how to get the term proportional to $\phi'$. The form of the Klein-Gordon equation becomes $g^{11}\phi''+\bigg[
\Gamma_{01}^0+\Gamma_{11}^1 +\Gamma_{21}^2+\Gamma_{31}^3
\bigg]g^{11}\phi'=\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi}$, which gives me a term proportional to $\phi'(r)$ given by $\frac{1}{r a(r)^2}(a'br+2ab)$. Are you positive there is a $rb'$ component in this term?

Comment: Also, according to the answer given here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/543134/metric-of-black-holes-with-scalar-hair, shouldn't your metric be $ds^2=\frac{a(r)}{r^2}(-b(r)dt^2+\frac{1}{b(r)}dr^2+r^2d\sigma^2)$?

Comment: I will compute it again using Mathematica first chance. If you look at equation 2.6 in the MTZ paper it looks exactly like the ansatz I wrote. I also think it does not matter since you can define $a(r) /r^2 = f(r) $ and once you obtain $f(r)$ you can find $a(r) $. The answer given there has very little connection to what I am asking seems it seems (as I write in edit 2) that the second degree of freedom for the metric in that particular form is essential for non trivial solutions.

Comment: Ok thank you. Also, btw I recalculated the equation again using your form of the metric and my previous term was off by a factor of two. I get $\Gamma_{01}^0=\frac{1}{2}(b'/b+a'/a)$, $\Gamma_{11}^1=\frac{1}{2}(a'/a-b'/b)$, $\Gamma_{21}^2=\Gamma_{31}^3=\frac{1}{2}(a'/a+2/r)$. Putting this altogether, I get the sum of Christoffel symbols as $\frac{2a'}{a}+\frac{2}{r}$. Hence, I get the term proportional to $\phi'$ as $\frac{1}{ra^2}(2ra'b+2ab)$, which is almost exactly what you have except off you have a factor of $rb'a$ while I have an additional $ra'b$.

Comment: I don't think that this might be the problem but do you use the correct form of $dσ$?? It's $sinh^2$ not $sin^2$.

Comment: I used $d\sigma^2=\left\{
\frac{d\rho^2}{1-k\rho^2}+\rho^2 d\phi^2
\right\}$. All the derivatives are with respect to $r$, so the $1-k\rho^2$ and $\rho^2$ terms cancel in the Christoffel symbol calculation.

Comment: No, this is a black hole spherically symmetric ansatz. It is $dσ^2 = dθ^2 + sinh^2 θ d\phi^2$. I don't know if what your using applies here.

Comment: I don't think this would matter, though. When calculating the Christoffel symbol, the $\sinh^{-2}\theta$ in $g^{33}$ should cancel with its inverse in $g_{33,\,1}$, right?

Comment: Yes i think so. I am calculating it right now.

Comment: I obtained the same $\Box$ term. I think the problem is with the Christoffels. I will post them in my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't you just have one Christoffel symbol term; i.e., $\square \phi=g^{rr}\phi''-g^{rr}\Gamma_{rr}^r\phi'$? This is because this term goes as $-\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^\alpha\partial_\alpha \phi$, and $\phi$ is just dependent on $r$.

Comment: No. The upper index of the Γ should match the derivative index. The down Γ indices will take all μ, ν indices. In this case the metric is diagonal so only μ=ν terms appear.

Comment: Ok, thank you. However, I still have one question. Based off this discussion: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/543134/metric-of-black-holes-with-scalar-hair and other work done on the MTZ solution, I originally wanted to map the form of the KG eqn from a generic metric to original MTZ metric (as you used). This question is too long for a comment, so I've asked it here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/559667/changing-variabels-between-two-different-metric-ansatzes-in-the-calculation-of-t If possible, I'd appreciate any opinion on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I actually found the problem I was having with the other problem (it was very minor). Thank you for all your help. The one thing I disagree with is the form of $d\sigma^2$ (I think it doesn't matter between your form or mine; I believe mine is just more general), but that is minor. This work is connected with research I'm working on. If you are comfortable with emailing me your name and affiliation, I'll thank you in the acknowledgements in the paper I (hopefully) will eventually write.

Comment: I'm glad that i helped @JoshuahHeath!!! There's no need for thanking me in your paper! Take care!!

Comment: @Noone, since you mentioned xAct, may I ask you how to treat a complex scalar field like the "charged" Klein-Gordon? It seems I can only define real scalar fields... Is it possible to do this in xAct?

Comment: @Quillo I haven't worked with charged scalars, but a colleague of mine may have worked. I will ask them and come back to you.

Comment: Thank you @Noone, I can not find any tutorial on this. Ofc finding, say, the equations of motions for the complex Klein Gordon from the action is very simple and xAct is not needed.. but it should also be a simple first pedagogical exercise that fir sure can be done with this package. Thank you again!

Comment: @Quillo they didn't use xAct for the charged scalars. So I recommend you to ask a question on the xAct google group!!